# Azure devops build pipeline depends on other build pipeline

Tags: azure, azure-devops

I have four projects. One is a common project for other three projects.

Other three project build pipeline are depend on common build pipeline. When common build pipeline is in progress, other three build pipeline should be wait until common build complete. How to achive this in on premise azure devops?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How to achive this in on premise azure devops?

You could add a PowerShell task at the beginning of the other three pipelines.

Here is Powershell script sample:

```
$token = "PAT"

$url="https://{instance}/{collection}/{project}/_apis/build/definitions/{definitionId}?includeLatestBuilds=true&api-version=5.1"

$token = [System.Convert]::ToBase64String([System.Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes(":$($token)"))



$response = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $url -Headers @{Authorization = "Basic $token"} -Method Get -ContentType application/json

$buildid = $response.latestBuild.id

$success = $false

do{
    try{
    $Buildurl2 = "https://{instance}/{collection}/{project}/_apis/build/builds/$($buildid)?api-version=5.0"
    $Buildinfo2 = Invoke-RestMethod -Method Get -ContentType application/json -Uri $Buildurl2 -Headers @{Authorization=("Basic {0}" -f $token)}
    $BuildStatus= $Buildinfo2.status 
    $result = $Buildinfo2.result
    echo $result
    echo $BuildStatus
 
   
        if($BuildStatus -eq "completed") {            

            write-output "No Running Pipeline, starting Next Pipeline"
            $success = $true 
                       
      } else {   
            Write-output "Pipeline Build In Progress, Waiting for it to finish!"  
            Write-output "Next attempt in 30 seconds"
            Start-sleep -Seconds 30         

            }
    
      
    }
    catch{
        Write-output "catch - Next attempt in 30 seconds"
        write-output "1"
        Start-sleep -Seconds 30
      # Put the start-sleep in the catch statemtnt so we
      # don't sleep if the condition is true and waste time
    }
    
    $count++
    
}until($count -eq 2000 -or $success -eq $true )
if ($result -ne "succeeded")
{
   echo "##vso[task.logissue type=error]Something went very wrong."
}

if(-not($success)){exit}
```

**Explanation:**

This powershell script runs the following two Rest APIs：

[Definitions - Get](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/build/definitions/get?view=azure-devops-server-rest-5.0)

[Builds - Get](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/build/builds/get?view=azure-devops-server-rest-5.0)

The script checks the status of the pipeline(by polling) that is in process. If the pipeline is completed and the result is successful, it will run the other three pipelines.  Or it will wait for the pipeline finishing the build.

**Result Sample:**

[image]